# Need Oracle sql query for grouping the date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with a date from 02/11/2015 to 01/12/2015. 
eg...

```
ATTNDATE
--------
02/11/2015
03/11/2015
--
--
--
01/12/2015.
```

This table may have some missing dates also.. Lets assume 06/11/2015 and 20/11/2015 is missing from this table.

I want to get an output like

```
SL.No      ATTNFROM          ATTNTILL
  1.       02/11/2015        05/11/2015
  2.       07/11/2015        19/11/2015
  3.       21/11/2015        01/12/2015
```

Kindly help me to get this output in oracle plsql

Comment: What did you try already? Any ideas?

Comment: What you need is LEAD or LAG analytic functions, which connects each date to the next one or last one. then check if the gap is bigger then 1

Comment: Hi.. I am using cursor to get the list of tables.. then i inserted 02/11/2015 in ATTNFROM column as first record.. then i m updating ATTNTILL for the remaining loops.. but I couldn't make record as i mentioned before...

Comment: Hi sagi,  I tried with LAG function.. it gives the output for each day and previous day but its not giving the output i have mentioned above.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you've written and perhaps someone can help correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with lead and lag analytic functions - in a subquery which you then group over, which may be what you missed - but you can also do it with an analytic 'trick'.

If you look at the difference between each date and the lowest date you get a broken sequence, in your case 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, ..., 27, 28, 29. You can see that with `attndate - min(attndate) over ()`.

You also have another unbroken sequence available from `row_number() over (order by attndate)`, which gives you 1, 2, 3, ... 28.

If you subtract one from the other each contiguous block of dates gets the same answer, which I've called 'slot_no':

```
select attndate,
  attndate - min(attndate) over ()
    - row_number() over (order by attndate) as slot_no
from your_table;
```

With this data every row gets either -1, 0 or 1. (You can add two to those to make them more friendly if you want, but that only really works if the gaps in the data are single days). You can then group by that slot number:

```
with cte as (
  select attndate,
    attndate - min(attndate) over ()
      - row_number() over (order by attndate) as slot_no
  from your_table
)
select dense_rank() over (order by slot_no) as slot_no,
  min(attndate) as attnfrom, max(attndate) as attntill
from cte
group by slot_no
order by slot_no;
```

With some generated data:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
with your_table (attndate) as (
  select date '2015-11-02' + level - 1 from dual connect by level <= 4
  union all select date '2015-11-07' + level - 1 from dual connect by level <= 13
  union all select date '2015-11-21' + level - 1 from dual connect by level <= 11
),
cte as (
  select attndate,
    attndate - min(attndate) over ()
      - row_number() over (order by attndate) as slot_no
  from your_table
)
select dense_rank() over (order by slot_no) as slot_no,
  min(attndate) as attnfrom, max(attndate) as attntill
from cte
group by slot_no
order by slot_no;

   SLOT_NO ATTNFROM   ATTNTILL 
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 02/11/2015 05/11/2015
         2 07/11/2015 19/11/2015
         3 21/11/2015 01/12/2015
```

If your real scenario is getting these ranges for multiple keys, say a person ID, then you can add a `partition by` clause to each of the analytic function calls, in the three `over ()` sections.

Comment: Alex Poole: Thank you for information.. I have got my output.. once again thank u so much